# Pass two objects to server AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have server mvc action with two parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestActionPost(string applicationId, Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary)
{    
   return null;
}
```

and ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#itemList").tableDnD({
            onDrop: function (table, row) {
                var items = $("table#itemList > tbody > tr[id]");
                var dict = [];
                var dataObject = [];
                $.each(items, function (index, value) {
                    dict.push({
                        key: value.id,
                        value: index
                    });
                });
                dataObject.push("123");
                dataObject.push(dict); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Admin/Applications/TestActionPost/",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    data: { applicationId: JSON.stringify(dataObject[0]), myDictionary : JSON.stringify(dataObject[1]) },
                    traditional: true,
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);                        
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I try to send data to server action, but my action can't call. I get code HTTP 500. 
Please,help me!

Comment: HTTP 500 means internal server error the problem is on your server-side.  See [status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Also check the server logs

Comment: I know what means it code. But I don't know what incorrect in my code.

Comment: Try debugging your application to see if you get an exception thrown when the action is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having issues with the way the dictionary is serializing which is causing an exception to be thrown when you call the action. [This article](http://growingtech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/binding-posting-to-dictionary-in-mvc-3.html) explains how to create dictionary object which can then be sent by an ajax post.